# I have a mobile robot that isn't supported by ROS. How should I structure the driver node(s) to expose my robot's integrated sensors and actuators?

Tags: ros, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please help in writing up a ROS best practice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11833/i-have-a-mobile-robot-that-isn%27t-currently-supported-by-ros.-how-should-i-structure-the-driver-node(s)-to-expose-my-robot%27s-integrated-sensors-and-actuators?/) by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8372 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2012-08-30**:
Should we create a wiki page with a tutorial for this answer? If so where should it be created (under the http://ros.org/wiki/Robots page)?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-30**:
That seems like a good place for a link, at least. "Want to add a robot to this list? Here's how."

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-10-09**:
Great suggestion !!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-09**:
I think it's hard to give a general answer. I would use a different software design for a simple robot such as a Roomba (i.e. one node per sensor) than for something like the PR2 (something like pr2_controller_manager and pr2_etherCAT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although this isn't yet a tutorial, http://ros.org/wiki/Robots

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-09**:
(so that this wasn't still listed as an unanswered question...)